# Locus of non-injective maps between vector bundles

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, vector-bundles

Suppose $E,F$ are two vector bundles of ranks $e$ and $f$ with $e<f$ on a smooth projective surface $X$ over $\mathbb{C}$ and let $r:=f-e$. I am interested in estimating the (co)dimension of the locus of noninjective maps (as sheaf maps or vector bundle maps, does not matter for me too much) inside $Hom(E,F)$.

This has a clear answer when the bundle $\mathcal{Hom}(E,F)$ is globally generated - the codimension of maps which are not injective on at least one fiber $E|_x \to F|_x$ is greater or equal to $r-1$.

Is there anything that could be said in the case when $\mathcal{Hom}(E,F)$ fails to be globally generated? In the situation I have at hand, $r \geq 3$ and I have at least one injective vector bundle map $E \to F$ and I want to rule out the situation when the locus of non-injective maps is divisorial, i.e. codimension 1 inside $Hom(E,F)$.

**Remark.** Something that appears potentially useful is that in my situation $X=\mathbb{P}^1 \times \mathbb{P}^1$ and $E,F$ are homogenous with respect to the action of $Aut(X)$.

Comment: A priori no. Imagine that $F = E \oplus E'$ with $\dim Hom(E,E) = 1$ and $Hom(E,E') = 0$. Then $Hom(E,F)$ is a 1-dimensional space, and the locus of non-injective maps in it is the point 0, so it is divisorial.

Comment: @Sasha, thank you for your observation. Are you aware of any weaker conditions I should be looking for to rule out a divisorial locus? Bundles $E,F$ are composed of exceptional bundles in my case, but as far as I can tell, not much is known about global generation for $\mathcal{Hom}$-bundles for bundles from an arbitrary strong exceptional collection on $\mathbb{P}^1 \times \mathbb{P}^1$.

Comment: What do you mean by saying "composed of"?

Comment: If $E,F$ are direct sums of vector bundles from an exceptional collection then Sasha's comment applies directly to your situation. Indeed split $E = G_{i_1}\oplus ...\oplus G_{i_q}$ and $F = G_{j_1} \oplus ... \oplus G_{j_p}$. Either all maps from $Hom(E,F)$ are non injective or forall $i_k$ there exists $j_k$ such that $G_{i_k} = G_{j_k}$ then applies Sasha's comment to $Hom(G_{i_k}, G_{j_k})$.

Comment: @Sasha,  I am working with resolutions of sheaves, arising from spectral sequences associated to an exceptional collection (and I pick a collection in such a way, that dual collection is strong).

Comment: @Libli, I am looking at a slightly different situation than what you are suggesting. A model case for me is resolutions of the form $0 \to \mathcal{O}(-1,-1)^a \to \mathcal{O}(-1,0)^b \oplus \mathcal{O}(0,-1)^c \oplus \mathcal{O}^d \to \mathcal{V} \to 0$. I want to replace the line bundles by objects from a different strong exceptional collection: $0 \to E_0^a \to E_1^b \oplus E_2^c \oplus E_3^d \to \mathcal{V} \to 0$.